# How do I modify cooking methods for a markedly smaller roast than most recipes state?

Tags: meat, temperature, cooking-time, roasting, lamb

I purchased a small boneless leg of lamb roast for my husband and I to enjoy as an Easter meal. It's about 2.5 lbs. (1.3 kg). I have experience dry roasting larger cuts of beef in the past, but nothing quite this size, and this is the first lamb roast for me. What cooking temperature and timeline should I target for a roast of this size? I know about the temperature I want the roast to be once it's done, just not sure how to get it there. I'm hoping for rare to medium-rare and I'm rather fearful of overcooking it.

Comment: 2 hours at 180 c for med rare.

Comment: Stick a thermometer in the roast, check after 80 mins @ 180C, extend as needed. 2h might be a bit much for such a small roast, but in case of doubt go by what the thermometer tells you.

Comment: Isn't that a bit on the long side? I'm seeing similar times/temps for a roast three times the size.

Answer (score 1):

It is past Easter but for future you may want to try this.  Get a saute pan or a saute pot you want to roast in, heat it and then brown your roast, all sides.  Before you do that, be sure you season your roast very well so that when you put it in the hot saute pan with the oil you are browning the dry seasonings also (be generous with your seasonings).  Once well browned take out of pan or if large enough pan take out of pan, put a rack on the bottom of the pot put the roast back in, cover, put in preheated 350 degree F oven for about 45 minutes to l hour, covered.  Temperature of roast should be 145 degrees for medium to medium rare.  Let sit for about 20-30 minutes.

Answer (score 1):

Indeed, with a thermometer you can determine exactly when your meat is the way you want it. Indispensable. If you really do not want to buy or use one, here is the BBC roast timer:

http://www.bbcgoodfood.com/howto/tools/roast-timer

Personally, I am a big fan of the reverse sear method: roast in a fairly cool oven until the meat is medium rare, and THEN sear it off in a hot pan. Much more evenly cooked and juicy. Read all about it here (it is about pork, but the idea is the same).

http://www.seriouseats.com/2015/11/how-to-make-pork-loin-roast.html

And do not forget to salt it well ahead, a day or even two (this one is about turkey, but it works on any kind of meat. The results are amazing):

http://www.seriouseats.com/2012/11/the-food-lab-the-truth-about-brining-turkey-thanksgiving.html

I think this is all you need to make perfectly amazing roasts. Good luck!